# Google authentication issue

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-oauth

My app is an flutter app.

I am enrolled in play app signing. And i have added the play app signing key, relase and debug key to the firebase console.

My app google auth works in the release and debug build but after publishing it to the play store it do not work.

I am getting exception code 10 i.e. developer error